# Group by one column with different values ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I have the next table:

```
NUMBER | ELEMENT
-------+----------
1      | Elemento1
1      | Elemento2
1      | Elemento3
2      | Elemento5
2      | Elemento6
2      | Elemento7
```

I am searching an group by select that returns me the next:

```
1 | Elemento1Elemento2Elemento3
2 | Elemento5Elemento6Elemento7
```

I tried with:

```
Select number, element from table group by number;
```

But it returns me `not a group by expresion`

Anyone knows how can I achieve this, if it is possible?

Thanks for your time

Comment: You are looking for `LISTAGG`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Answer (score 2):

Use `listagg` :

```
Select number_, listagg(element) within group (order by element) as elements
From your_table
Group by number_
```

Cheer!!